# What is causing "Cannot fast-forward to multiple branches" during `git pull` in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

We use the default workflow on GitHub, i.e., create a feature branch, push some commits to it, merge to master. Nothing fancy.

In the **master** branch, I only ever **pull** newer changes from GitHub, never push. In visual terms, the "down" direction in VS Code typically contains some commits while the "up" direction doesn't:

[image]

Now, from time to time (not always!), invoking the sync in VS Code which is `git pull origin master` ends up with this error:

```
> git pull origin master
From https://github.com/shoptet/sofa
 * branch                master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: Cannot fast-forward to multiple branches.
```

What does the error mean? I don't see any multiple branches.

It's important to note that after I run the operation **again**, it **works**. So my workflow usually is:

1. Click the "sync" button in VS Code (runs `git pull origin master`)
2. See the "Cannot fast-forward to multiple branches" error, dismiss it.
3. Click the "sync" button again, see it succeed.

A bit annoying.

BTW my repo is in a clean state:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

One additional thing that can be related as I think this problem only started happening after I enabled it is `ff=only` in my Git config – the full section looks like this:

```ini
[pull]
    rebase = false
    ff = only
```

I also looked in the VS Code logs and there's an additional `git fetch` before – I'm not sure if this changes something or not:

```
[2022-05-04T06:27:11.853Z] > git fetch [2373ms]
[2022-05-04T06:27:11.853Z] From https://github.com/shoptet/sofa
 * [new branch]          1997-fix-pnpm -> origin/1997-fix-pnpm
 * [new branch]          debug-build   -> origin/debug-build
[2022-05-04T06:27:11.892Z] > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD [3ms]
[2022-05-04T06:27:11.897Z] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master [4ms]
[2022-05-04T06:27:11.901Z] > git remote --verbose [3ms]
[2022-05-04T06:27:11.905Z] > git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname) [7ms]
[2022-05-04T06:27:11.909Z] > git config --get commit.template [3ms]
[2022-05-04T06:27:12.498Z] > git pull origin master [1918ms]
[2022-05-04T06:27:12.498Z] From https://github.com/shoptet/sofa
 * branch                master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: Cannot fast-forward to multiple branches.
```

I'd like to understand what the error means and how to get rid of it.

I'm on Git 2.36.0 and VS Code 1.66.2.

Comment: What's left behind in the `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file, and what version of Git is VSCode invoking?

Comment: I've seen similar every now and then for some months, also after enabling `ff = only`. git v2.35.1 and `FETCH_HEAD` contains a single `branch` and multiple `not-for-merge` branches. The issue always resolves by itself when attempting a 2nd pull.

Comment: @torek exactly the same as @voneiden, except the Git version which is 2.36.0 in my case (VSCode has this in its logs: `Using git 2.36.0 from /opt/homebrew/bin/git`).

Comment: @voneiden is that with VSCode too, or would this be a pure Git bug of some sort?

Comment: @matt I've only ever seen this in VSCode, never in terminal. However, in terminal, I do just `git pull`, not `git pull origin master` preceded by `git fetch` so it's not exactly the same.

Comment: That message appears twice in this file: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/pull.c

Comment: @BorekBernard Yes, I don't use VSCode and I never say `git pull` so I'm unlikely to see this one. :)

Comment: @matt That's a great pointer, the message appears ("pseudocode"!) `if (merge_heads.nr > 1) && opt_ff && !strcmp(opt_ff, "--ff-only")`, see [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0f828332d5ac36fc63b7d8202652efa152809856/builtin/pull.c#L1101-L1105). I wonder why `merge_heads.nr` is greater than one in my case.

Comment: Can you show your remote/fetch configs? `git config --get-regexp remote`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question directly, but please note that if, like many of us in cooperative situations, "In the master branch, I only ever pull newer changes from GitHub, never push" because merging is done only through pull requests, _you do not need a local `master` branch in the first place._ My recommendation would be to delete your `master` entirely and change your work habits. (Let me know if you don't see how you would operate without a `master`.)

Comment: @PhuNgo Here: https://gist.github.com/borekb/26b59dd2d232f9971b92b4ba17c3bbec.

Comment: @matt Yes if you could expand on that or link me to some blog post or similar, that would be great. I've never heard of a workflow where you don't have a local master/main branch.

Comment: Well, what do you need it for? If you need to run / compile the app in its latest state, you can check out `origin/master`. If you need to make a new feature branch, you can base it off of `origin/master`. If you need to update, you just `fetch`. And Bob's your uncle, as we say.

Comment: The pull code is supposed to skip over any of the "not-for-merge" lines. However, now that `pull.c` is C code that actually just re-uses the existing `fetch.c` code, perhaps there's a bug in it, that wasn't there before when it was `pull.sh` and used grep... (Also, the "resolve on retry" happens because the *second* fetch doesn't have any other branch names to update.)

Comment: @matt I'm CLI only, but now that I think of it have bash-git-prompt that does automatic fetching in the background. Could possibly be a clash between fetch and pull commands running simultaneously?

Comment: @matt automatic pull is opposed to the whole spirit of Git, but I don't mind automatic fetch. In my workflow, there's never a time when I really want to know where origin/main was in the past, I just want to know where it is now... :)

Comment: Let's not derail with feelings @matt, thanks. I'd still like to note that prior to setting `pull.ff = only` I never encountered this issue with the legacy/default pull behaviour of earlier git versions (which would in my workflow typically result in FF). I used that setup for years before I added `pull.ff = only`. So I'm inclined to believe that the newer FF only behaviour stumbles on something that the legacy behaviour didn't.

Comment: Maybe related issues https://superuser.com/questions/1773580/why-does-git-pull-sometimes-fail-but-a-second-git-pull-always-succeeds or issue on github https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt/issues/523 do you have other sw that might interact with the project folder at a same time?

Answer (score 6):

From this related GitHub issue ticket: [Git error (Cannot fast-forward to multiple branches.) when syncing during autofetch #158309](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/158309), quoting jeffrson, the cause of the issue appears to be this:

> Apparently, `git fetch` can run during `sync` (or the other way around). If this occurs, there might be an error, requesting to open Git log, which contains "Cannot fast-forward to multiple branches".

A fix is still pending. You can give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it getting fixed, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. But please avoid making noisy comments there like "+1" / "bump". I'll keep this answer post updated.

Though I haven't tried, someone in the comments here says they can work around it by doing `git fetch --all` and then `git pull`.

Comment: VS Code shall use `git fetch --no-write-fetch-head` to do autofetch.

Comment: I stumbled upon this even though I am not using VSCode. Just plain git in a terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: @eja you're in the wrong place. go look for a Q&A that is just about git and that doesn't involve VS Code. This question is specifically about git operations performed through VS Code.

Comment: @eja @starball Although the question is about VS Code, the problem is when multiple `git fetch` (of `git pull`) run simultaneously (e.g. some GUI tool does `git fetch` in the background.) in general. Depending on your use case, just repeat the action, configure your tools not to fetch in background or use `git fetch --no-write-fetch-head`.

Comment: though not a fix, doing `git fetch --all` and then doing `git pull` allows me to proceed.